# Clear connection gigecam object

Tags: matlab, camera

I have a gige camera connected to my PC. Via the gigecamlist command I see the camera is connected. I want to (re)connect to this gige camera via the gigecam command but I get the errormessage:

"Camera failed to open. It could be in use in another MATLAB session or another
application."

I do not have the camera object in the workspace, so there's nothing to clear. The only way to get connection to the camera again is restarting the Matlab session and use the gigecam command again.

How can I clear the gigecam object without restarting Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`delete`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/imaq/delete.html):

```
g = gigecam
preview(g);
delete(g);
```